# Pandas : Convert 1D dataframe to 2D dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe whose shape is `(4628,)`.
How do I change the shape of dataframe to `(4628,1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have a Series, you can turn it into DataFrame with `Series.to_frame`

```py
s = pd.Series(range(10))

out = s.to_frame('col_name') # or .to_frame()
```

```
print(s.shape)

(10,)

print(out.shape)

(10, 1)
```

Don't know how you get that Series, if you use a label like `df['a']`, you can try passing a list of labels instead, like `df[['a']]`

Comment: @spb Add some guessing.

Comment: Actually, I had used label like df['a'] instead of df[['a']], that was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function called reshape(). It's easy to use. Run the code and you'll see the result from (4628,) to (4628,1).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(range(1,4629))
print(df)
df = df.values.reshape(-1)
print(df.shape)
df = df.reshape(-1,1)
print(df.shape)
```

Results:

......

[4628 rows x 1 columns]

(4628,)

(4628, 1)